# Dual display issues on HP laptop?

Tags: laptop, hp

Folks,
just installed my working laptop (HP Folio 9470m) with Elementary Juno simply because so far it seems the most well-crafted desktop distribution around these days, however pretty quickly I run into a peculiar issue: On my device, dual-screen setup with an external monitor and the device in a docking station doesn't work. What happens is:

- Initial issue: I can't disable the laptop display. Though I can "turn it off" in the elementary monitor settings, it still stays on and apparently also active.
- Worse: If I close the laptop lid (to still disable the unused display) and lock my session, the unlock screen always will be on the laptop display and completely ignore my external monitor.

This is *rather* strange. I very well could live with the laptop display not deactivated, but the unlock screen (as well as the login screen) should be on the primary display. Is there some way to set things up just like this?

Thanks in advance and all the best,
Kristian