# Can't turn off the secondary display

Tags: display

I tried to turn off the dispaly on my laptop, because I'm  using a secondary display and I used [this guide](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16445/monitor-settings-do-not-work-cannot-disable-integrated-screen-of-the-laptop), but it's not working. I get the error message saying

`bash: eDP-1-1: No such file or directory`

but when i use

`xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'`

it says that the display name is  eDP-1-1. Could someone help me?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the output of that command? I mean exact output, its for verifying something.

Comment: i have this problem too when you use the gui to turn monitor off it doesn't do anything.